# How to use jinja2 i18n with bottle (with babel)

Tags: python, internationalization, jinja2, bottle, python-babel

I believe to use jinja2 with bottle one simply uses jinja2_template instead of template:
e.g. bottle.jinja2_template("mytemplate", dict(name=value, name2=value2))
However if one needs the i18n jinja extension how is that best specified to also do

```
....install_gettext_translations(
```

? Is that done automatically with

```
bottle.jinja2_template("mytemplate", dict(name=value, name2=value2), template_lookup=['templates'],'template_settings'=   {'extensions':['jinja2.ext.i18n'],'autoescape': True }))
```

? Thanks.

Upon further reflection, I think I may need to overide the prepare method in class Jinja2Template to add the env.install_gettext_translations(   ???

More info ,if I were doing  ....install_gettext_translations( manually, perhaps:

```
tenv = Environment(extensions=['jinja2.ext.i18n'])
tenv.install_gettext_translations(gettransobj())

import gettext
import locale 

def gettransobj():
    loc = locale.getlocale()
     # change to reflect where your mo files are
    mofilename = "res/messages_%s.mo" % locale.getdefaultlocale()[0][0:2]
    try:
       trans = gettext.GNUTranslations(open( mofilename, "rb" ) )
    except IOError:
       trans = gettext.NullTranslations()
    return trans
```

OR for babel translations obj something like

.....install_gettext_translations(gettransobj(),newstyle=True)

```
import babel
import locale 

def gettransobj():
  loc = locale.getlocale()
  mofilename = "res/messages_%s.mo" % locale.getdefaultlocale()[0][0:2]
  trans = babel.support.Translations(open( mofilename, "rb" ) )
```

If this code is somewhat correct, not sure where to put it? Not very familiar with jinja2. Just once at top of program or per bottle.jinja2_template call.

On a different note, if someone needs to do extraction using babel, see jinja2.ext.babel_extract

Another approach is getting trans obj with something like:

```
return gettext.translation(domain, localedir=localedir,languages=languages, codeset='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from jinja2 import FileSystemBytecodeCache, Environment
bcc = FileSystemBytecodeCache('/tmp', '%s.cache')

template_settings = {'filters': {
                       'tojson': json_util.dumps
                     },
                    'bytecode_cache': bcc,
                    'extensions': ['jinja2.ext.i18n'],
                    'languages': ['en_US']
                    }

import bottle
from bottle import Jinja2Template
from babel.support import Translations

TEMPLATE_PATH = bottle.TEMPLATE_PATH
DEBUG = bottle.DEBUG
TEMPLATES = {}

class Jinja2BabelTemplate(Jinja2Template):
    def prepare(self, filters=None, tests=None, 
                      languages=['en_US'], 
                      globals={}, **kwargs):
        from jinja2 import Environment, FunctionLoader
        self.env = Environment(loader=FunctionLoader(self.loader), **kwargs)
        #BABEL: this is where we load and install our translations from babel
        translations = Translations.load('translations', languages)
        self.env.install_gettext_translations(translations)
        if filters: self.env.filters.update(filters)
        if tests: self.env.tests.update(tests)
        if globals: self.env.globals.update(globals)
        if self.source:
            self.tpl = self.env.from_string(self.source)
        else:
            self.tpl = self.env.get_template(self.filename)


def jinja_template(*args, **kwargs):
    tpl = args[0] if args else None
    adapter = Jinja2BabelTemplate
    lookup = kwargs.pop('template_lookup', TEMPLATE_PATH)
    languages = kwargs.pop('languages', None)
    tplid = (id(languages), tpl,)
    if tplid not in TEMPLATES or DEBUG:
        settings = kwargs.pop('template_settings', {})
        if languages: settings.update({'languages': languages})    
        if isinstance(tpl, adapter):
            TEMPLATES[tplid] = tpl
            if settings: TEMPLATES[tplid].prepare(**settings)
        elif "\n" in tpl or "{" in tpl or "%" in tpl or '$' in tpl:
            TEMPLATES[tplid] = adapter(source=tpl, lookup=lookup, **settings)
        else:
            TEMPLATES[tplid] = adapter(name=tpl, lookup=lookup, **settings)
    if not TEMPLATES[tplid]:
        abort(500, 'Template (%s) not found' % tpl)
    for dictarg in args[1:]: kwargs.update(dictarg)
    return TEMPLATES[tplid].render(kwargs)

template = functools.partial(jinja_template, 
                            template_settings=template_settings)


#and now you should be able to use the template function above with different languages

@get('/home')
def home():
     data = {}
     return template('home.html', data, languages=['en_US'])
```

Comment: You need to specify what you have don in the answer. Pasting code only doesn't make any sense.